# What is it? [ulisting] in html page and $listing in php page. Is it related?

Tags: php

I just faced a project. I saw an html page, some of code are below:

```
<div class="span6">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="col-wrap control-label" for="username">User ID</label>
                        <div class="col-wrap controls">
                        <select name="username" id="username" class="span12">
                        [ulisting]
                        </select>
                        <br><div id="show_hide" class="show_hide"><font color="Red">User ID Already Exist</font></div>
                        </div>
```

And I found this in php file:

```
$ulisting ="";

    $url = 'http://'.$_SESSION["url"].'/-/vo/public/user.api_userlist?sess='.$_SESSION["sessid"].'&format=json';

    $content1 = file_get_contents($url);

    $json = json_decode($content1, true);

    foreach($json['user'] as $item) {

        $name=$item['name'];

        $ulisting=$ulisting. "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>";

    }
```

After I analysed that code, I thought its related. Can anyone explain me what is it? What is the keywords to find some article about this? I want to learn how its works.. Thank you..

Comment: And you saw the *literal text* `[ulisting]` in the final HTML sent to the client? (If it was seen in an HTML [template] file, such that the actual HTML sent to the browser contained the actual $ulisting variable's value, then it might be some odd/one-off/home-grown template system.)

Comment: Did you mean I saw [ulisting] in the final PHP sent to the cilent (HTML)? If you did. Yes, I saw it. So I can find article about html template. Thank you, sir.

Comment: If you saw it in the final HTML, then the PHP that generated the HTML is possibly broken. It means nothing special in the HTML and it appears that all the code to generate the option elements was discarded. (On the other hand, there isn't a technical reason why there isn't some absolutely horrible JavaScript munging with such output and "doing magic".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also find something that looks like this

```
$template=str_replace('[ulisting]',$ulisting,$template);  //or a diff way to replace
```

That `[ulisting]` is just a marker the programmer put there so that using PHP they can replace it with actual values for the select field later on. If that is not done, then it means nothing special and should display in html as it is.

If the replacement is actually there, then obviously this would add option values to your select box and there wont be any text `[ulisting]` in the final output HTML.

Comment: Yes, I found it. what is str_replace for?

Comment: It is a function to replace something in a string. So your HTML template is a string and http://php.net/str_replace will replace [ulisting] in that string with the value of PHP variable which contains the actual options. Then you can print that html.